# Запрет доступа в локальную сеть через WiFi

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, wifi, nat, linksys

Имею Linksys EA4500, подключил его к внутренней сети `10.0.0.0`. Он раздает сеть `10.0.5.0`, и гостевую сеть `192.168.3.0`. Так вот вопрос, как из гостевой сети запретить доступ к сети `10.0.0.0`? Не хочу чтобы при прописывании `\\10.0.0.0` попадали в сетевые папки. Спасибо.

Вижу на уровне роутера это запретить невозможно, думаю логично тогда будет запретить доступ на уровне шлюза, подскажите как это сделать в Ubuntu, если  запрещать сетевой доступ какие это порты? или разрешить лучше только порт proxy)  Думаю... дальше)

Comment: Эй таких как ты много с wifi, в общем если сделал то отпиши как? оч надо..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извините, это тоже я, который Anton Reshin. Просто, с другого логина зашёл. Там, для таких, ещё отдельную подсеть надо на роутере сделать.

Comment: Ограничил все на уровне сервера, дабы не мучатся в настройках роутера.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, [где-то тут](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&app=vw&vw=1&login=1&json=1&docid=f35bd58fda4148929ac482f3c7968e04_Guest_Network_Frequently_Asked_Questions.xml) должно быть...

Скорее всего:

> №15.  Can I set Access Restrictions specifically for the Guest network?
>
> No.  Restrictions set on your main network like Internet restrictions policy and Parental Controls also apply to the Guest network.  You cannot set a separate protocol for the Guest access feature.  To learn how to set up Parental Controls, click [here](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=21458).

Сетевые папки централизовать ([DFS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System)?) и централизовано оставить доступ только из своей подсети.

Comment: я подключил его к внутренней сети, для него шлюз интернета - моя внутренняя сеть, я хочу запретить доступ в внутреннюю сеть шлюза)

Comment: Возможно, тогда лучше использовать ["родительский контроль"](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=21458)... В любом случае - тщательно "курить маны", изучать [FAQ-и](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-eu/support/routers/EA4500).

Comment: Родительский контроль интересная мысль, надо попробовать... попробую отпишусь, но уже через 2 недельки (после отпуска). Спс, за совет

Comment: Как прошел отпуск?;)

Comment: Руки не доходят взять ноут и пойти проверить) проверю полюбому

Comment: Родительский контроль запрещает только: 1 - Определенным юзерам (которые уже имели хоть одно подключение) 2 - только 80 и 8080 порты (только сайты). Короче сетевой доступ к папкам так и остался(

Answer (score 1):

Если в линксисе была бы консолька как у TP-Link ([ссылько](http://demura.su/articles/about_blog/tp-link_probros_portov_i_mnogoe_drugoe/)), то можно было как в Unixe прописать iptables на сеть, ну а так попробуй прописать в правилах обрубать все пакеты начинающиеся с одной сети которые идут в другую, вроде это можно.

Comment: я пробовал, она не хочет iptables левый вставлять)

Answer (score 0):

Ещё как даже можно!!! Просто раздавать им фиксированные адреса с маской 255.255.255.255 - и усё!!! А раздавать можно по MAC-адресу. И на роутере это можно настроить!